# Python regex not working in my script as expected

Tags: python, regex

I am reading an EXCEL cells column with text to capture numbers between text string.  For example:

```
'Of. 806 some text' or 'Some text Of. 0959' (end of sentence)
```

Numbers have fourt digits but if number have three digits fail with this regex patern, and n_ofi_resument returns "none".

```
elif "Of. " in oficina_resumen:
    patron = re.compile(r'Of.\s(\d{1,4})$|Of.\s(\d{1,4})')
    n_ofi_resumen = patron.search(oficina_resumen, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to match? only the numbers?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://regex101.com/r/2XhI7Q/1). Besides, your regex can be optimized and the `.` stands for every character, so `Ofi`, `Ofx`, `Of?` and so on will also be matched. You could e.g. simply go for [`Of\.\s+(\d{1,4})`](https://regex101.com/r/2XhI7Q/2/), your alternation with `$` in the end is pretty useless.

Comment: With the little detail provided, why no just try `r'Of.\s(\d{1,4})\s'`?

Comment: @Jan my bad, has to be scaped. Didn't notice because the op was saying that the problem was later on the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I test your proposals and I show you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
patron = re.compile(r'Of\.\s+(\d{1,4})')
```

– probably there's more than one space between `Of.` and the number. Also, I have no idea why you tried using alternative.

Comment: I apologize because Of. and the 4 digits can be at the beginning or at the end of the sentence.